# NullPointerException Android ActionBar Back (but not Menu Bar Back)

Tags: android

I get an error with the ActionBar back button when I'm moving back to a previous activity, but when I use the Menu Button Back, everything works as planned! I think I have an idea of what is going on, because using the Action Bar back button causes a recreation of the previous activity, but I don't want that to happen. How do I override the Action Bar (default) back button to perform like the Menu Bar back button so that OnDestroy() is not called?

Comment: Post some code. Also, you might just want to call finish(); when the action bar is clicked. You are never supposed to remake the previous activity.

Comment: Post your relevant code and the LogCat errors so we can help you.

Comment: AH, NEVER MIND. Silly me, figured it out. I fixed the issue by using a finish() call in the OnMenuitemClicked rather than the default, silly me . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to call `finish()` in my `onMenuItemClicked` function rather than using the default function.

This answer may be outdated though.